# R: How to calculate the difference between each value of a dataframe with all elements of another dataframe in the same row?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes. X includes companies from one country and their share price at a corresponding date, Y includes companies from another country and their share price at a corresponding date.
The first column of X/Y is the date, the following columns include share prices of the companies (one column for one company). Here is how the data X looks like:

[data X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5Rzo.png)

The goal is to find pairs of companies (one company from X and one company from Y) which have the smallest relative difference in share prices for every day. Therefore I have to calculate the relative difference between the price of company x1 and all companies y1,y2,...,yn for every day t. Then relative differnce between x2 and y1,y2,...,yn for every t ...... and so on.

Comment: Please can you use the `dput()` function to embed some sample data from your X and Y dataframes? E.g. `dput(head(X, 10))`... Also, what have you tried so far? One possibility is to merge the two dataframes by the date column, then work out the difference between X price and Y prices.

Comment: why not just a loop?

Comment: Hi TPrie, please provide a minimum reproducible example. That means give us a copy of your data that you created with dput,and provide enough R code that we can cut and paste into our own R sessions to reproduce your issue. Lot of people would like to help but do not have time to re-enter all your data or code from scratch. We want to get to the stuck place you have already got to. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn´t know how to copy some sample data properly. Thank you for the tip with "dput()". I will use it the next time.

Comment: I would use `tidyr::gather(dat, company, share_price, -dat)` to obtain a data.frame `df` with (date, company, share_price). Then do `full_join(df, df, by = "date")` to create all possible pairs of companies (might be big!). You can then `mutate(PriceDiff = share_price.x - share_price.y) %>% group_by(company.x, company.y) %>% summarise(RMSDiff = sqrt(mean(PriceDiff^2))) %>% arrange(RMSDiff)` to find the companies whose share prices are closest on average.

Comment: However it does not really make sense to do that: I guess you want to find correlated companies, i.e. companies whose share price evolve in the same way, not companies with close absolute share price. Classically one would look at the correlation but if you don't want to do that, you should at least look at price evolution instead of price every day.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with two for loops. The Next problem was that the results were not saved in a vector. Therefore I created the vector k to get a vector of the results of the for loop.

```
k <- numeric(0)
  for(i in 2:ncol(X)){
   for (j in 2:ncol(Y)){
    k <- c(k, (X[,i]-Y[,j]))
   }}
k
```

j and i start at 2 because the date is in the first column which i don´t need for calculations.